# How do you create a growl notification with jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have an select field which updates the datbase with an ajax call.

When the user changes the select field, I'd like to display an obtrusive message for .5 seconds that says "Database updated" and then close by itself.

I'm not seeing a way to do this using just jquery mobile. Maybe I need a plugin? I googled around and nothing jumped out at me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little jquery plugin did the trick: http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Tiny-jQuery-Plugin-For-Informative-Messages-In-The-Browser-Growler.html